# What is the difference between T, E & P series Intel processor

Tags: cpu, intel-core2

I am looking at buying a new laptop and there seems to be a whole lot of processors to choose from. I am highly confused with the Core 2 Duo's with the T, P & E series processors. Can someone please shed some light on the differences between them?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

E = Desktop.

T = Laptop.

P = Newer Laptop... (However some of the high end T series are better than the lower P ones).

Answer (score 1):

Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor Family
Processor numbers for the Intel® Core™2 Duo processor family brands are categorized with an alpha prefix followed by a four-digit numerical sequence. The table below explains the alpha prefixes used for the Intel® Core™2 Duo processor family.

Alpha Prefix    Description
E   Desktop energy efficient dual-core processors with TDP greater than or equal to 55 W
L   Mobile highly energy efficient with TDP 12-19 W
P   Mobile highly energy efficient processor with TDP 20-29 W
Q   Mobile quad-core high performance processors
QX  Desktop or mobile quad-core extreme performance processors
S   Mobile small form factor with 22x22 BGA package
T   Mobile highly energy efficient processors with TDP 30-39 W
U   Mobile ultra high energy efficient with TDP less than or equal to 11.9 W
X   Desktop or mobile dual-core extreme performance processors